# What are these little plants with round leaves, growing in my potting soil?

Tags: identification, seedlings

I have plants growing in my seedling pots that I didn't put there.  The potting soil says it's weed-free.  What are these plants?

[image: Unknown plant]

Comment: Are they all or most around the edge, and did you reuse the pot?

Comment: It will be difficult to identify this seedling until it grows larger.

Comment: @EdStaub Yes, they are mostly around the edge and yes, I did reuse the pot although I replaced the soil.

Comment: You know where I'm going, right?  I figure some tiny seeds were stuck to the side of the pot.  If you can remember what you grew in the pot last, it might be telling.

Comment: @OmPatange have these gotten any bigger yet?

Comment: IS that Creeping Charlie?

Comment: Looks maybe like morning glory, but until it's bigger would be impossible to tell.

Comment: FYI: [discussion](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/q/481/26) about this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient photographic evidence to make a positive Id. Please update the photo so it can be reopened.